# Safe way to build dynamic query using Npgsql

Tags: sql, format, npgsql

I need to build a query to select from a different table based on input parameter.

I'd like an alternative to the unsafe version:

```
string.Format("SELECT x FROM {0}.{1}", "schemaname", "tablename")
```

What's the best way to go about this using Npgsql?